# Rails ActiveRecord: How to eager-load objects through two polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to eager-load `Comment`s when querying my `Activity` table.

```
# Activity (basic FB-style news feed)
#   user_id
#   primary_source_id (polymorphic object, like "Post", that can have comments)
#   primary_source_type

# Comment (acts as commentable w/ threading gem)
#   user_id
#   commentable_id
#   commentable_type

# WHAT GOES HERE?!
# How do I eager-load comments?
activities = Activity.includes(???).joins(???)

# Display code
activities.each do |activity|
  render ... # render activity
  activity.root_comments.each do |comment|
    render ... # render activity's comments
  end
end
```

See, I render my page by looping through `Activity`s and grabbing each `primary_source` (like a `Post`) and its `Comment`s. Right now the `primary_source` is being eager-loaded, but the `Comment`s are not; each loops hits the `Comment` table. This is a huge performance hit for me, which scales linearly with the number of `Activity`s I show.

How do I eager-load my `Comment`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all of your primary_sources are commentable,

```
activities = Activity.includes(:user, :primary_source => :comment_threads).where...
```

...worked for me. To avoid hitting the database (and defeating the purpose of the includes) you'll have to replace any references to root_comments with comment_threads (which do include child comments). This is because root_comments is actually defined in the gem (lib/acts_as_commentable_with_threading.rb) as a helper method:

```
def root_comments
  self.comment_threads.where(:parent_id => nil)
end
```

Sources: The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) section on nested associations, along with peeking inside the acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem and a little trial and error in the console :)

Comment: this led me to the right thing for mine, which looked like: `Pin.includes(comment_threads: [:children]).find(params[:id])`